# XNA-Content getting changed after rebuilding solution

Tags: xna

So, I was experimenting with different types of textures in an XNA game which I have created, when I suddenly ran into an unexpected problem.

The textures which I was changing were not getting reflected in the game. They were not changing. I was about to put up this question on StackOverflow when it suddenly occurred to me to Rebuild the entire solution. On doing so, however, I could see all the textures which I had intended to change.

Why did this happen? Why did I have to rebuild the solution in order to see my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How XNA handles it's content it converts assets into compiled XNB files. By building the solution (or rather the content project) you are telling visual studio to recompile the content files in order to reflect the changes that you have made.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447745.aspx